# Serial Port Send Data in VB.NET with Packed message

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I have the Manual of Programming protocol,  but when I write code vb.net returns error message.

The following is the table structure of bytes array

position    1      2      3      4      5      6      7  8

Name        SOH    LEN    SEQ    CMD    DATA   Post-amble     BCC    ETX

Lenth/bytes 1  1      1      1      0-200      1      4      1

Value   (01h)   (20h-FFh)   (20h-FFh)   (20h-FFh)   (20h-FFh)   (05h)   (30h-3Fh)   (03h)

**Abbreviations:**

**“SOH”**- (Start Of Heading) start of packed message

**“LEN”**- total number of bytes from position 2 to position 6, plus fixed offset of 20h.

**“SEQ”**- serial number of packet. SLAVE puts the same “SEQ” in the reply message. In case when SLAVE
receives a message with the same “SEQ”and “CMD” like the last correctly received message, the device ignores
the message and repeats the last packet sent to the HOST.

**“CMD”** – code of command

**“DATA”**- data, according to the command. If there is no data, the length field is zero.

**“BCC”** – control sum(0000h-FFFFh). Sum of data bytes from position 2 to position 6. The control sum is
transferred in ASCІІ type (12АВ is transferred as 31h 32h 3Аh 3Вh).

**“ETX”** – (End of TeXt) end of packed message.

**Codes sample:**

Public Class Form1

```
Private WithEvents sp As System.IO.Ports.SerialPort

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    For Each y As String In System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames
        Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add(y)
    Next
    sp = New IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM4")
    sp.StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
    sp.BaudRate = 9600
    sp.DataBits = 8
    sp.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
    sp.Handshake = IO.Ports.Handshake.None

    sp.Open()
    Dim by As Byte = &H20

    ' MsgBox(&H20)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim By(9) As Byte
        By(0) = 1
        By(1) = &H2 + &H20
        By(2) = &H58
        By(3) = &H45
        By(4) = &H5
        Dim S As String = Hex(&H58 Xor &H45)
        '  MsgBox(S)
        By(5) = &H30
        By(6) = &H30
        By(7) = &H31
        By(8) = &H3D
        By(9) = &H3

        sp.Write(By, 0, By.Length - 1)
       ' MsgBox(sp.ReadByte)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub sp_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles sp.DataReceived
    Dim rec As System.IO.Ports.SerialPort = sender
    MsgBox(Hex(rec.ReadByte))
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Could you rewrite the question? It's difficult to understand what you're asking for.

Comment: I have EFD machine from daisy technologies (e xpert SX) am writing code in vb.net to send command. One of command code is 45h to print z report. I tried to write code as shown above but returns error. may be because of BCC. I don't know. Please healp.

Comment: There are a *lot* of things wrong with this code.  You should not hard-code the values.  SEQ number needs to be a variable for example.  BCC needs to be calculated.  The most glaring thing you got wrong is the sp.Write() call, don't subtract 1 from by.Length

Comment: Thank you Hans Passant. Could you give me some example of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annael you could probably do this, by invoking an updating function and giving a delay of 500ms will make a difference. Now on receiving data you can receive input data

```
Dim inputData As String = ""// Declare this as a global variable in the program
    Private WithEvents sp As System.IO.Ports.SerialPort

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   For Each y As String In System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames
            Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add(y)//the code you have written to add Serial ports

SerialPort1.PortName = ComboBox1.Text//this will access your com port as your button
        Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim by As Byte = &H20    
                By(0) = 1
                By(1) = &H2 + &H20
                By(2) = &H58
                By(3) = &H45
                By(4) = &H5
                Dim S As String = Hex(&H58 Xor &H45)
                '  MsgBox(S)
                By(5) = &H30
                By(6) = &H30
                By(7) = &H31
                By(8) = &H3D
                By(9) = &H3
            SerialPort1.BaudRate = 115200
            SerialPort1.Open()
            SerialPort1.Write(By)
        Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As System.Object, e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived

            Threading.Thread.Sleep(500) ' 500ms delay induced to receive the email
            inputData = SerialPort1.ReadExisting 'or SerialPort1.ReadLine


            Me.Invoke(New EventHandler(AddressOf DoUpdate))

    Public Sub DoUpdate()

                MsgBox(inputData)
```